# Elastic Search query_shard_exception failed to execute query on datetime field

Tags: elasticsearch

recently I use Kibana for get data from ElasticSearch.

There are that node:

```
  { "_index" : "impasti",
    "_type" : "impasti",
    "_id" : "2019-01-02T15:25:20",
    "_score" : 1.9806902,
    "_source" : {
      "sensor" : "Temperature",
      "mac_address" : "",
      "time" : "2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z",
      "unit" : "'C",
      "value" : 20.937
    }},
```

I try get the data by the *time* field, into datetime range or exactly datetime.
But when I run this query

`POST /impasti/impasti/_search
{'query':{
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "time",
      "query": "2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z"
    }
  }
}`

the response is an error like this:

```
"type": "query_shard_exception" "reason": "Failed to parse query [2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z]",
```

Where is the mistake?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error states that you would need to do something more in order for the ES query parser to understand that the value is a `date` and not a `string/text/keyword` type:

Moreover date fields are usually used for a particular range. Below is how it can be done via adding [Range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges) feature

### Using query_string:

```
POST your_index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "time",
      "query": "time:[2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z TO 2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z]"
    }
  }
}
```

Generally it is `[min To max]` for finding docs in specified time range, but in case if you want to find documents for that date, mention same date for both `min` and `max`.

### Using Range Bool Query:

```
POST you_index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "mydate": {
              "gte": "2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z",
              "lte": "2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above is an example of [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) using query DSL

Alternatively you can also make use of a simple match query to get what you want whilst using query DSL via [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html), that is because internally it is stored as `long` value.

```
POST your_index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mydate": "2019-01-02T14:25:19.728709Z"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Elasticsearch internally stores the date values in the form of `long` datatype in its inverted index as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)

Comment: So good! Now it's ok. But if I want use this querystring with the Filter on the "sensor" field? I try to use the filterd, but It response "no [query] registered for [filtered]"

Comment: Could you update that query which gives you this error in the question. I can quickly check and let you know.

Comment: Sure! This is the query   POST /impasti/impasti/_search
{
  "query":   {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
              "default_field": "time",
              "query": "time:[2019-01-02T14:20:19.728709Z TO 2019-02-02T14:25:19.728709Z]"
              }
            }, 
            
      "filter":
      {
          "term":{ "sensor": "temperature" }
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

> Could you update that query which gives you this error in the question. I can quickly check and let you know.

Sure! 
This is the query

```
`POST /impasti/impasti/_search{
      "query":{
           "filtered": {
               "query": {
                   "query_string": {
                       "default_field": "time",
                       "query": "time:[2019-01-02T14:20:19.728709Z TO 2019-02-02T14:25:19.728709Z]"
                    }
               }, 

               "filter": {
                   "term":{ "sensor": "temperature" }
                }
         }
     }
}`
```

It get this error:

```
no [query] registered for [filtered]
```